# ngx-chips: it's not possible to add a second tag from autocompleteItems

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-chips

I'm using `ngx-chips` with `autocompleteItems` for tags input, but after adding the first tag, the dropdown is not appearing anymore and also there is no error in the `console`.

**HTML**

```
<tag-input
    [ngModel]="columnsToIgnore"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
    [placeholder]="'Enter variables to ignore'"
    [secondaryPlaceholder]="'Enter variables to ignore'"
    [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true"
    (onAdd)="addIgnoreColumn($event)"
    (onRemove)="removeIgnoreColumn($event)"
    theme='bootstrap'>
     <tag-input-dropdown
       [autocompleteItems]="selectedDataset.schema.columns"
       [displayBy]="'name'"
       [focusFirstElement]="true">
          <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
            {{ item.name }} : {{ item.type }}
          </ng-template>
     </tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>
```

when adding the first `tag`, the dropdown appears
[image]

but when trying to add a second one, the dropdown does not appear
[image]

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feyu3j)

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in stackblitz ?

Comment: @SunilSingh I added a link to stackblitz

Comment: Added the answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the complex `object` as `options` you should use `identifyBy` through which `ngx-chips` will compare the selected items with provided options.

```
 <tag-input
    [ngModel]="columnsToIgnore"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
    [placeholder]="'Enter variables to ignore'"
    [secondaryPlaceholder]="'Enter variables to ignore'"
    [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true"
    (onAdd)="addIgnoreColumn($event)"
    (onRemove)="removeIgnoreColumn($event)"
    theme='bootstrap'>
     <tag-input-dropdown
       [autocompleteItems]="selectedDataset.schema.columns"
       [displayBy]="'name'"
       [identifyBy]="'name'" <!-- use any property of object -->
       [focusFirstElement]="true">
          <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
            {{ item.name }} : {{ item.type }}
          </ng-template>
     </tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icraz4